# SharePoint 365 Method Post of object IOWSPostData failed

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am getting the following error when importing data from an excel spreadsheet into a list in SharePoint 365. This is a brand new environment of SharePoint 365:

[image]

Has anyone ran into this issue when using SharePoint online 365?

Im using office 2016 btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following power shall:
Scenario: My requirement is to import data from CSV file to SharePoint online list from a local drive, every day!

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"



##Variables for Processing

$SiteUrl = "<a class="vglnk" href="https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/POC/" rel="nofollow"><span>https</span><span>://</span><span>crescent</span><span>.</span><span>sharepoint</span><span>.</span><span>com</span><span>/</span><span>sites</span><span>/</span><span>POC</span><span>/</span></a>"

$ListName="Contacts"

$ImportFile ="c:\Scripts\EmpData.csv"

$UserName="Salaudeen@crescent.com"

$Password ="Password goes here"



#Setup Credentials to connect

$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))



#Set up the context

$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 

$Context.Credentials = $credentials



#Get the List

$List = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)



#Get the Data from CSV and Add to SharePoint List

$data = Import-Csv $ImportFile

Foreach ($row in $data) {



#add item to List

$ListItemInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation

    $Item = $List.AddItem($ListItemInfo)

    $Item["FirstName"] = $row.FirstName

    $Item["LastName"] = $row.LastName

    $Item["Department"] = $row.Department

    $Item["Mobile"] = $row.Mobile

    $Item.Update()

    $Context.ExecuteQuery() 



}

Write-host "CSV data Imported to SharePoint List Successfully!"
```

Comment: where did you get the $SiteUrl string from? `"<a class="vglnk" href="https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/POC/" rel="nofollow"><span>https</span><span>://</span><span>crescent</span><span>.</span><span>sharepoint</span><span>.</span><span>com</span><span>/</span><span>sites</span><span>/</span><span>POC</span><span>/</span></a>"`